# Terraform: Optional fields in Resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

In terraform I'm trying to create some firewall rules, which normally don't have logging enabled - to accomplish this, I must *not* have the log_config field created. However, I have a variable firewall_logging, which if true, should add this field and the options I wish it to contain.

I don't think using a dynamic here is quite the right thing to do but it's possible it is and I've misunderstood how to generate it, instead I came up with the following:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "this" {
  name          = var.name
  project       = var.project
  network       = var.network
  source_ranges = var.source_ranges
  source_tags   = var.source_tags
  target_tags   = var.target_tags
  priority      = var.priority
  direction     = var.direction

  allow {
    protocol = lower(var.protocol)
    ports    = var.ports
  }

  ##  If log_config is defined, this enables logging. By not defining it, we are disabling logging.
  var.firewall_logging == true ? log_config { metadata = var.log_metadata } : null
```

I was hoping that the variable would be evaluated, and if true, the log_config section is added to the resource but I get an error that  a argument or block definition is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work using [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html). For instance:

```
dynamic "log_config" {
  for_each = var.firewall_logging == true ? [true] : []
  content {
    metadata = var.log_metadata
  }
}
```

Comment: You know when you see a solution to a problem, after staring at the problem for so long with no idea how to fix it, and the solution is so simple that you feel stupid? That's me right now. Obviously need to test it but thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help, hope it works for you :)

Comment: Don't edit it, I was reading my output wrong :D, the dynamic creates the section, so it is correct as you have it originally ;)

Comment: Ok, logically this makes sense to me, but for some reasson it's not working :(

Comment: The code works in a test however, it doesn't update existing rules ! - this seems to be part of a number of bugs around the move from using enable_logging, to log_config. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/7309