# Terraform - Don't create log_config on firewall rules unless enabled

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create some firewall rules in GCP which optionally have the logging turned on or not.

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "this" {
  name          = var.name
  project       = var.project
  network       = var.network
  source_ranges = var.source_ranges
  source_tags   = var.source_tags
  target_tags   = var.target_tags
  priority      = var.priority
  direction     = var.direction

  allow {
    protocol = lower(var.protocol)
    ports    = var.ports
  }

  ##  If log_config is defined, this enables logging. By not defining it, we are disabling logging.
  log_config {
            metadata = var.log_metadata
  } 
}
```

What I need to achieve, and can't figure out, is how to have the log_config block defined when I have var.firewall_logging set to true (or some other string if we can't use a boolean) and not have the log_config block *at all* when it's set to false. I tried using a dynamic, as in my other question [Optional fields in resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738630/terraform-optional-fields-in-resource/68738959?noredirect=1#comment121481552_68738959) however, even when set to false, it's still creating the log_config block.

Comment: You should add more detail to your existing question if the existing question isn't answered. Follow up questions should be for when you have a related but not the exact same problem. As it is, that answer _should_ work so it suggests you aren't showing enough detail. I'd suggest editing the original question so you have a [mcve] with all the inputs defined for both enabling and disabling it and then it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Also you shouldn't mark an answer as accepted if it doesn't fully answer your question. As you still have the same problem you should instead be discussing with the answerer what doesn't work for you before marking it as accepted.

Comment: I'm not voting for it just yet because gold tag badge means an automatic close but I think this should be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68738630/2291321

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I presume I can't close it myself?